# React Typescript type-safe children props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

First up, I'm 'fairly' new to React therefore might not have all the knowledge there is.

Anyways, I would like to create a component that pre-defines the children props of each component inside. This is to ensure the correct id and text values of the children components, like shown in the example below:

```
type IDs = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type Text = 'Hello World' | 'React' | '...'

class SomeComponent<P> extends React.Component<P> {
    ...
}

() => (
    <SomeComponent>
        <div id='a'>
            <div id='b'>
                {'Hello World'}
            </div>
        </div>
        <p id='c'>{'React'}</p>
    </SomeComponent>
);
```

I'm totally open for new and different approaches to this, only requirement is to ensure type-safety of the id and text before runtime.

Thank you very much for any help provided to that topic

Comment: You can't type children, it already has a type: `React.ReactNode`. If you know the text and IDs ahead of time, why not just have your component exactly as you wrote it? I don't understand how the ids and text relate, especially since you just have them as unions rather than a mapped type.

Comment: @JaredSmith The issue is I don't know the correlation between the text and ids yet. I only know what ids and text have to be included in that component, but not how. I'm given a dataset of ids and texts that need to be designed in React, while the structure can be different, the data has to be correct

Comment: Is there a mapping? Like id a will always be with text content b? Or is it any combination? This is kind of underspecified: either you're not giving us enough detail or they're not giving you enough.

Comment: @JaredSmith The text correlates with the id, yes. It's based on it, but then again I would like to provide the ids to all components before runtime. I'm working on a system which is based on a pre-specified dataset and which produces a static webpage based on the data and structure provided in Next.js. The ids and text have to be used correspondingly to allow for secure programming of these webpages

Comment: **Again**, this is underspecified. How are you supposed to enforce integrity with typings for pieces of data that you don't understand the relationships of? How are *we* supposed to help you when even *you* don't yet understand the problem? You need to get more data from your stakeholders. You can do something like `const MyComponent = <T extends Text, U extends IDs>({ children }: { children: React.ElementType<{ id: U, text: T}> }) => <whatever />` But that isn't very helpful. For one thing it has no concept of nested children.